# Finding the sum of primes below 10

Tags: python-3.x, primes

```
>>> k=1
>>> sum=0
>>> for i in range (2,10):
        for j in range (2,i):
            if ((i%j)==0):
                k=0
    if (k==1):
        sum+=i


>>> print(sum)
    5
```

I don't know why, but this code, instead of giving 17 as an output, always gives 5.

Comment: You only need to check up to `i/2`

Comment: @pala_: up to the square root of `i`, actually.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set your `k` flag back to `1` each time the `for i` loop moves to the next number:

```
for i in range (2,10):
    k = 1
    for j in range (2,i):
        if ((i%j)==0):
            k=0
    if (k==1):
        sum+=i
```

Without doing that your code only ever finds `5` to be a prime number, and ignores anything after that.

Note that in Python, 0 is considered *false* when used in a boolean context (such as an `if` statement), 1 is true, so you can just use `if k:`. Better still, use `True` and `False` and better variable names, such as `is_prime` rather than `k`. You can drop a lot of those parentheses:

```
sum = 0
for num in range (2, 10):
    is_prime = True
    for i in range (2, int(num ** 0.5) + 1):
        if not num % i:
            is_prime = False
    if is_prime:
        sum += num
```

I also made use of the fact that you only need to check up to the square root of a number to see if there are divisors, cutting your loops down significantly.

Last but not least, you can make use of the `for ... else` construct; if you use `break` in a `for` loop, the `else` branch never gets executed, but if the `for` loop completes to the end without breaking out, it *is*; this removes the need for a boolean flag:

```
sum = 0
for num in range (2, 10):
    for i in range (2, int(num ** 0.5) + 1):
        if not num % i:
            break
    else:
        sum += num
```

Comment: Great answer Mr. new moderator

Comment: And what do i do if i need to find the summation of primes below a very big number, for instance, one million? My code, after making the changes regarding the 'k' variable, isn't working in this case.

Comment: @sbhayana26: finding all primes up to 1 million takes a little while with this method. If you used my method (only test up to the square root) it'll be a little faster. The sum is 37550402023, it works just fine. There are [faster ways still](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n) using sieves.

Answer (score 0):

Along side the @Martijn Pieters answer that note the problem you can use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within `sum` :

```
>>> sum(i for i in range(2,10) if all(i%j!=0 for j in range(2,i)))
17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum=0
limit=10
for n in range(2,limit+1):
  if all(n % i for i in range(2, n)):
    sum += n
print sum

Output: 17
```